# Three.js - Showing/Hiding part of an object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking to create a 3D character using Three.js, with the character having different faces for different textures and also having different items (E.g. holding a sword or a dagger).

Is it possible to use one 3D object and show/hide different parts of that object using three.js?
For example, the object could have a dagger and a sword, but the user only sees the dagger in one scenario, or the sword in another scenario?

Or would I need to use different 3D objects and load them all into the same canvas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a custom shader and add custom attribute to your geometry - every vertex will have a attribute with which you can hide(discard) every fragment it creates

there is a complete example here

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_selective_draw

Comment: Sorry for my naivety, but is that only for custom drawn geometric shapes, or does that apply to 3D object files too (E.g. .obj files).

Comment: when you load a file, it creates geometry - add custom attribute to it, material has to be custom too(copy the one it creates and add discard code to fragment shader and pass code for the attribute to vertex shader), then you have to know which vertices represent the dagger etc. and toggle those, the example is the bare minimum so it is easy to understand